# Select for update for skip locked is not working

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, transactions, innodb

I have a use case where multiple instances read data from DB and call an external API.
Now I have to make sure that each instance read unique data.
For that, I am using select for the update using skip locked.

The query is to get the free entires and process them

select for update Query : "select * from abc where process = 'NOTPICKED' order by updated_at desc LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"

After that, I am marking the status for those entries to be 'PICKED'
Update query : "update abc  set process = 'PICKED' where hqc.customerId IN (ids)

I am getting into LockTimeoutException when running its multiple instances when debug found that the same record is processed by multiple instance which means that select for update query is not returning the unique set.

I have created an index on the updated_at column.
DB is MySQL and using INNODB engine

Answer (score 0):

How long are taking between the `SELECT` and the `COMMIT`?  I should not be more than a few seconds.

It smells like a queuing mechanism?  And you are picking 10 items *inside* a transaction to work on before `COMMITting`?

If each item can be processed in less than, say, one second, then 10 at a time may be reasonable.  But, if each item takes more than a second, pick them only one at a time.

Furthermore, if an item takes more than, say, 10 seconds, do *not* hang onto the transaction while processing it.  Devise some other mechanism to "acquire" and "release" the item.

One approach involves having the `UPDATE` to "pick" the item *and* assign your process's id to a column.  But have that `UPDATE` and the "unpick" `UPDATE` be in separate transactions, independent of the actually processing.  (3 transactions per item)